# Set document title through shortcode plugin

Tags: php, shortcode, title

I have a plugin a web hosting company made for us, and I need the "current challenge" page to show the challenges name as the document page title. Currently it just displays the page name "Current Challenges" that contains the shortcode to show the challenge.

The challenge system only had a show challenge list function, which I just limited to 1. But now that I am trying to add the title I made a new function to just show latest added challenge that is published. Why isn't this working though?

```
function display_latest_challenge($args){
    global $post;
    $challenge_default_args = shortcode_atts(array(
    ),$args);
    $challenge_args = array(
            'posts_per_page'   => 1,
            'orderby'          => 'date',
            'order'            => 'DESC',
            'post_type'        => 'scwd_challenge',
            'post_status'      => 'publish'
        );
    $challenge_string = "";
    $challenges = get_posts( $challenge_args ); 
    
    ob_start();
    foreach ( $challenges as $post ) {
        
        add_filter('pre_get_document_title','challenge_page_title');
    
        ?>
        <div class="chalList">
            <?php setup_postdata($post); $img = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/images/placeholder.png';?>
                <div class="chalSingle">
                    <?php include get_template_directory() ."/template-parts/scwd-challenge/challenge-title.php"; ?>
                    <?php include get_template_directory() ."/template-parts/scwd-challenge/challenge-info.php"; ?>
                    <?php include get_template_directory() ."/template-parts/scwd-challenge/challenge-winner.php"; ?>
                    <?php include get_template_directory() ."/template-parts/scwd-challenge/challenge-sponsor.php"; ?>
                    <?php include get_template_directory() ."/template-parts/scwd-challenge/challenge-prize.php"; ?>
                    <?php include get_template_directory() ."/template-parts/scwd-challenge/challenge-contestant.php"; ?>
                </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
        
    }

    $challenge_string = ob_get_clean();
    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $challenge_string;
}

add_shortcode("show_latest_challenge",'display_latest_challenge');

function challenge_page_title($data){
    global $post;
    return $post->post_title;
}
```

Comment: `pre_get_document_title` is for the page title shown in the tab, aka the `<title>` tag in the header, it has nothing to do with headings in the page itself, that's why your filter does nothing. Otherwise it's not possible to tell you how to implement this as there is no source code for `challenge-title.php`

Comment: And if you did indeed want the title in the tab to be that challenge then that's not possible, by the time your shortcode runs the title has already been generated and sent to the browser. It's the classic closing the barn doors when the horse has already bolted, it can't be done from a shortcode via that filter

Comment: @TomJNowell well, yes, that's literally what I am trying to do hence "document page title".

Comment: @TomJNowell That's unfortunate if it's not possible. This whole challenge system this place did is just done through shortcode, but went through all the trouble of making all this admin area and challenge post type. I guess I'll just use a jQuery script.

Comment: Also Weirdly, when I do do these methods, it does change the title, it replaces the whole website title which is "Page - NWDA - New Worlds Awaits" with just "Page" with none of the other stuff. So it is doing something, just not actually getting the data I am trying to pass.